# Product of projection maps

Tags: general-topology, tensor-products, projection

Given a Cartesia product of finitely many sets (say 3 for simplicity) $X_1\times X_2\times X_3$, we denote the set-theoretic projection map $\text{proj}_j:X_1\times X_2\times X_3\longrightarrow X_j$ as the map $\text{proj}_j(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_j$. I believe it is also called canonical projection. Say we want to define a similar concept for the product, say for example $\text{proj}_{i,j}:X_1\times X_2\times X_3\longrightarrow X_i\times X_j$ as the map $\text{proj}_{i,j}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_i,x_j)$. The map is well defined, but is there a standard notation/construction for such a map? Cartesian product does not feel right, it applies to sets, I feel $\text{proj}_i\times\text{proj}_j$ is too informal. Is it perhaps tensor product? Like $\text{proj}_i\otimes \text{proj}_j$? Thanks in advance for any info you are able to share

Comment: For readability, the best would be $\operatorname{proj}_{i,j}$. If you don't like that, I think $\operatorname{proj}_i\times \operatorname{proj}_j$ is fine. You may also use $(\operatorname{proj}_i,\operatorname{proj}_j)$, since for general $f : X\to Y$ and $g : X\to Z$ it is common to write the induced map $X \to Y\times Z$ as either $f\times g$ or $(f,g)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly tensor product, but composition of tensor product and diagonal map.

In general for $f:X\to Y$ and $g:A\to B$ we define
$$
f\times g : X\times A \to Y\times B,\quad (f\times g)(x, a) = (f(x), g(a))
$$
which you could call tensor product or Cartesian product of maps.
For any space $X$ we define diagonal map as
$$
\Delta: X \to X\times X, \quad \Delta(x) = (x, x).
$$

In your case you have projections $\pi_j : X_1\times X_2 \times X_3 \to X_j$.
What you want to achieve is
$$\pi_{ij} : X_1\times X_2 \times X_3 \to X_j \times X_j, \quad \pi_{ij}(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (x_i, x_j)
$$
which can be done as composition
$$
\pi_{ij} = (\pi_i \times \pi_j) \circ \Delta.
$$

This is often done not only for projections; for $f:X \to Y, g:X\to Z$
you can define
$$
(f, g) :X \to Y\times Z, \quad (f, g) = (f\times g) \circ \Delta
$$

I know name of this composition in polish (*"zestawienie funkcji"*), but couldn't find English name.

Comment: I see, you need the diagonal map to make the concept of starting with two copies of the initial space rigorous, while leaving the overall map starting from just one copy of it. Thank you very much, I see that perhaps the notation $\text{proj}_{i,j}$ is probably best then, as $\text{proj}_i\times\text{proj}_j$ feels too much of an abuse. Would you agree on this?

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{proj}_i \times \operatorname{proj}_j$ could be confused to have bigger domain $(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3)^2$.

Comment: thank you so much for your time